# Same Javasript function working for one set of buttons and not for the other

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that toggle the hidding and showing of a dropdown list. The following are the codes

**The below function is for one set of buttons. I am posting one of them(Function 1)**

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function civilmenuFunction() {
  document.getElementById("lawsmenudropcivil").classList.toggle("lawsshow");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.lawsdropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("lawsdropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('lawsshow')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('lawsshow');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Same Function for another button for a different dropdown (Function 2)**

```
function moresearchoptions() {
  document.getElementById("search-options").classList.toggle("more-search-show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.more-search-btn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("search-options-dropdowncontent");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('more-search-show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('more-search-show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What the above functions do is when the user clicks on the button the dropdown is shown and when the user clicks on the window outside the dropdown the dropdown closes.

The problem I am facing is if I write the **Function 2** below **Function 1** then the dropdown works fine for the button linked with **Function 2** but for **Function 1** when I click on the window the dropdown doesn't close. Similarly if I do the reverse that is if I write **Function 2** above **Function 1** then the dropdown associated with **Function 1** works correctly but the dropdown associated with **Function 2** doesn't work.

I am a beginner in Js so I am unable to figure out the porblem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Also I removed the Django tag. There is no Django here and please only post redendered HTML in the example

Comment: Also 

`[...document.querySelectorAll(".lawsdropdown-content.lawsshow")].forEach(drop => drop.classList.remove("lawsshow"))`

Comment: thnak you sir..

Comment: you're doing `window.onclick = /* your function */` in both cases, so whichever one comes second *overwrites* the value of the first. You should be using `addEventListener` instead to add event listeners (to the `document` rather than `window`) so that you can have both of these handlers simultaneously. (Or if you insist on using `window.onclick`, you'll have to assign that just once, to a "master" function that calls both of your individual functions.)

Comment: Okay sir, thank you I have to learn it and then I shall aplly it.